# How to iterate alerts in Prometheus Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to get timestamp (value of StartsAt) into email body of any alert.
There is need to iterate alerts, to get timestamp from element. 
 Need help, how to do that properly, so that exact timestamp of that generated alert will be collected in description of yaml file?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample from the Prometheus documentation (for how to iterate over all alerts): https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/notification_examples/#ranging-over-all-received-alerts

Copy-paste that, and replace `.Annotations.summary` with `.startsAt`. I.e.

```
"{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .StartsAt }}\n{{ end }}"
```

For reference, the data structures available to Alertmanager notification templates are documented here: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/notifications/

Comment: Thank you Alin, I have added text: line in 'alertmanager.yml'
```
text: '{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .startsAt }}\n{{ end }}'
```
... Still get error in log of alert manager.  level=error ts=2019-02-05T09:54:17.691429576Z caller=dispatch.go:280 component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=1 err="cancelling notify retry for \"email\" due to unrecoverable error: executing email text template: template: :1:22: executing \"\" at <.startsAt>: can't evaluate field startsAt in type template.Alert"
How to use this for email alerts ?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong documentation (JSON format vs. notification template reference). It appears that you need to use an uppercase `S` in `.StartsAt`.

Comment: Updated my answer with a template that should hopefully work (still not tested, though).

Comment: Thank you Alin,  After using,  the line  text:  '{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .StartsAt }}\n{{ end }}' , errors disappeared.    Now trying to display that time in email body. trying to get value of time, under Labels or Annotations (Summary, description etc.)

Comment: It is still difficult to get Alerts.StartsAt, or alerts.StartsAt or .StartsAt or alert.StartsAt or alert.StartsAt into email body for the notification.

Comment: I still get `<error expanding template: error executing template ... " at <.Alerts>: can't evaluate field Alerts in type struct { Labels map[string]string; ExternalLabels map[string]string; Value float64 }>` — the documentation of prometheuhs/AM is ridiculous

Comment: _(ok so apparently `.Alerts`, `.Alert`, `.StartsAt` are only available from the template (eg, `email.default.html`) or the `receivers:` part of `alertmanager.yml`, but NOT from the alert rules. One cannot define an alert message as `error xxx since {{ .StartsAt }}`. Instead, the template outputs the details of the alerts )_

Comment: Indeed, this is Alertmanager templating (i.e. within the `alertmanager` process). Alert rules are evaluated within Prometheus, along with all other recording rules and Prometheus knows nothing about e.g. `.StartsAt`, that's Alertmanager bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

```
- alert: Alert
  for: 5m
  expr: ...
  annotations:
    timestamp: >
      time: {{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }}{{ end }}
```

Instead of iterating alerts, I have solved this problem in above way. 
It works, and I am able to get timestamp in email body. Cheers.!

Comment: Dear @Chintaman, what does char '>' means in timestamp as value?

Comment: I found the answer here https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/block/scalar